# How can I get a unique identifier for a pen flash

Tags: c#

I don't care if it is changeable or resets if formatted. I am wanting to get a unique identifier that tells me which flash drive I am working with. Most online examples I have found are concerned with security. I am not. I am concerned with user convenience.

I have found this code for getting the Serial Number from the drive as well as filtering for only flash drives:

```
var theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
foreach (var currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{currentObject["Caption"]} | DeviceID = \t{currentObject["SerialNumber"]}");

    foreach (var property in currentObject.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{property.Name}\t{property.Value}");
    }
}
```

This works great. I'm unable to find however whether the "SerialNumber" value is unique enough. That is, if the user uses two of the same flash drives, am I going to get the same value for "SerialNumber"?

If not, is there a unique value I can access in code?

Comment: Maybe by using the Device Instance ID? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @gnalck, I thought of that. I believe that device ID is relative to the port and device instance ID changes when the device is detached and reattached. I could be wrong.